# VLAN Internet access

Tags: cisco, routing, router, vlan, nat

I am trying to configure my Cisco 2800 router to communicate between VLANs and route traffic to the Internet. VLANs can access each other but not the Internet. The router can ping the modem but not the Internet. The configuration is below of the router:

```
Current configuration : 2904 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 03:36:32 UTC Thu Apr 27 2017
!
version 15.0
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
boot-start-marker
warm-reboot
boot-end-marker
!
enable password tyson987
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
!
!
dot11 syslog
ip source-route
!
!
ip cef
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.3.1 192.168.3.50
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.4.1 192.168.4.50
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.200
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.250
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.251
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.252
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.253
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.254
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.10.200
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.10.250
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.10.251
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.10.252
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.10.253
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.10.254
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.20.200
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.30.200
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.40.200
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.2.2
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.2.240
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.2.250
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.2.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.3.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.3.200
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.2.200
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.4.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.4.200
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.2.200 192.168.2.254
!
ip dhcp pool DHCP-ADMIN
   import all
   network 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 192.168.3.200
   dns-server 8.8.8.8
!
ip dhcp pool DHCP-STUDENTS
   import all
   network 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 192.168.4.200
   dns-server 8.8.8.8
!
ip dhcp pool DHCP-SERVER
   import all
   network 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
   dns-server 8.8.8.8
   default-router 192.168.2.200
!
!
ip name-server 192.168.2.2
ip name-server 8.8.8.8
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2821 sn FHK1307F1JZ
!
redundancy
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 !
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 192.168.10.200 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 192.168.3.200 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.30
 encapsulation dot1Q 30
 ip address 192.168.4.200 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.2.254 255.255.255.0
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 !
!
ip default-gateway 192.168.5.200
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 110.142.236.228
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/1
!
!
!
!
!
!
control-plane
 !
!
!
line con 0
 password tyson987
 login
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 password tyson987
 login
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
end
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

You did not configure `ip nat inside` on the layer-3 LAN interfaces. Nor do I see where you have defined the addresses to be translated. Also, you should not have two default routes the way you do.

Example:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10
 ip nat inside
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.20
 ip nat inside
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.30
 ip nat inside
!
ip nat inside source list 10 interface GigabitEthernet0/1 overload
!
access-list 10 permit 192.168.10.200 0.0.0.255
access-list 10 permit 192.168.3.200 0.0.0.255
access-list 10 permit 192.168.4.200 0.0.0.255
!
```

Comment: I will be grateful to you if you kindly post all the command necessary to work. Thanks.

Comment: I believe what I did post will work.